# Android Studio Problems-XML Desing/Text

Tags: android

I just want to create 3 fileds and 1 Button.
-2 Input 
-1 Output.
When i start the Emulator or so on, 4 things stuck left in the corner. :/
Can mabye someone help me?
Thank you!

http://prntscr.com/fjamzc

Comment: You should add the code to and not an image.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs:

When you drop a view into the Layout Editor, it stays where you leave it even if it has no constraints. However, this is only to make editing easier; if a view has no constraints when you run your layout on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the top-left corner).

So you lack constraints, there is a button to do so, again from the official docs:

Instead of adding constraints to every view as you place them in the layout, you can move each view into the positions you desire, and then click Infer Constraints  to automatically create constraints.